# Async await on Nodejs API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I'm trying to execute a function after another function (API call) has returned its result. The problem is, the program always ends up executing the second one before the first one has given the result.

The thing is, I need to place a contact email on a Mailing List using Mailjet, but first I have to create that contact. So, the contact creation works, but not the placement on the list, as this function is executed before the contact creation finishes.

I tried multiple things for some days, mostly using async/await, but I still don't get my head around it.

Here's my code:

routes/index.js

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, name } = req.body;
  const mktListId = process.env.MAILJET_ID_MARKETING;

  try {
    const contactCreated = await createContact(email, name);
    addEmailToList(email, mktListId);
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'Email Successfully subscribed to Marketing List' });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
});
```

```
function createContact(email, name) {
  const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APIPUBLIC,
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APISECRET
  );
  const request = mailjet.post('contact', { version: 'v3' }).request({
    IsExcludedFromCampaigns: 'true',
    Name: `${name}`,
    Email: `${email}`,
  });
  request
    .then(result => {
      console.log('result mailjet create contact', result.body);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error mailjet create contact', err.statusCode, err.ErrorMessage);
    });
}
```

```
function addEmailToList(email, listId) {
  const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APIPUBLIC,
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APISECRET
  );
  const request = mailjet.post('listrecipient', { version: 'v3' }).request({
    IsUnsubscribed: 'true',
    ContactAlt: `${email}`,
    ListID: `${listId}`,
  });
  request
    .then(result => {
      console.log('result mailjet add to list', result.body);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error mailjet add to list', err.statusCode, err.ErrorMessage);
    });
}
```

Any help with be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are not returning a promise from or using await in your functions and, therefore, await doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you @Kon, how can I do that though? I still don't get how promises work, although I've been reading a lot of articles about them. I mean, what promise should I return?

Comment: You just need to return `request.then().catch()` in `addEmailToList` and then `await addEmailToList(email, mktListId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a promise, await doesn't really do anything.

```
await new Promise (resolve => {
    console.log ("A");

    resolve ();
});
await new Promise (resolve => {
    console.log ("B");

    resolve ();
});
await new Promise (resolve => {
    console.log ("C");

    resolve ();
});
```

The create function needs to look more like:

```
function createContact(email, name) {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(
          process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APIPUBLIC,
          process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APISECRET
        );
        const request = mailjet.post('contact', { version: 'v3' }).request({
          IsExcludedFromCampaigns: 'true',
          Name: `${name}`,
          Email: `${email}`,
        });
        request
          .then(result => {
            console.log('result mailjet create contact', result.body);

            resolve ();
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('error mailjet create contact', err.statusCode, err.ErrorMessage);

            reject ();
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: If `request` returns a `Promise`, then why can't they just return `request.then().catch()` instead of having doing `new Promise` (which is an anti pattern)?

Comment: That's probably possible also, although `resolve (null)` in in the catch block is also an option.  I never really use `reject`.  (belief in anti patterns is an anti pattern)

Comment: Rejecting/throwing the error would definitely be important for error handling at the parent. Maybe update to `resolve(result)` and `reject(err)` so parent can access result and error via try/catch or similar?

Comment: Your suggestion worked @BryanGrace! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is the clean finished and refactored code:

*routes/index.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const emailController = require('../controllers/emailController');

router.post('/', subscriberValidationRules(), validate, emailController.create);
```

Then we put the router logic on:

*controllers/emailController.js*

```
const { createContact, addEmailToList } = require('../helpers/addEmailToList');

const create = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, name } = req.body;
  const mktListId = process.env.MAILJET_ID_MARKETING;

  try {
    await createContact(email, name);
    await addEmailToList(email, mktListId);
    return res.status(201).send({ message: 'Email Successfully subscribed to Marketing List' });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: err,
    });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  create,
};
```

And then our functions on:

*helpers/addEmailToList.js*

```
const createContact = async (email, name) => {
  try {
    const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(
      process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APIPUBLIC,
      process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APISECRET,
    )
    const { body } = await mailjet.post('contact', { version: 'v3' }).request({
      IsExcludedFromCampaigns: 'true',
      Name: `${name}`,
      Email: `${email}`,
    })
    console.info('result mailjet create contact', body)
    return body
  } catch (err) {
    console.info('error mailjet create contact', err.statusCode, err.ErrorMessage)
  }
}

const addEmailToList = async (email, listId) => {
  const mailjet = require('node-mailjet').connect(
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APIPUBLIC,
    process.env.MAILJET_MASTER_APISECRET
  );
  try {
    const { body } = await mailjet.post('listrecipient', { version: 'v3' }).request({
      IsUnsubscribed: 'true',
      ContactAlt: `${email}`,
      ListID: `${listId}`,
    });
    console.info('result mailjet add to list', body);
    return body;
  } catch (err) {
    console.info('error mailjet add to list', err.statusCode, err.ErrorMessage);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createContact,
  addEmailToList,
};
```